# Applying a design pattern for a certain behavior

Tags: php, design-patterns, refactoring

I was wondering if anyone could provide a design pattern or better implementation solution for this function:

```
  public function refundAcceptedDisputes() {            
        $this->getRequestedEbayOrdersFromDB(); //get all disputes requested on ebay
        foreach ($this->orders as $order) { /* $order is a Doctrine Entity */
            try {
                if ($this->isDisputeAccepted($order)) {
                    $order->setStatus('accepted');
                    $order->refund(); //refunds the order on ebay and internally in my system
                    $this->insertRecordInOrderHistoryTable($order,'refunded');                        
                } else if ($this->isDisputeCancelled($order)) {
                    $order->setStatus('cancelled');
                    $this->insertRecordInOrderHistory($order,'cancelled');
                    $order->rollBackRefund(); //cancels the refund on ebay and internally in my system
                } else if ($this->isDisputeOlderThan7Days($order)) {
                    $order->closeDispute(); //closes the dispute on ebay
                    $this->insertRecordInOrderHistoryTable($order,'refunded');
                    $order->refund(); //refunds the order on ebay and internally in my system
                }
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $order->setStatus('failed');
                $order->setErrorMessage($e->getMessage());
                $this->addLog();//log error
            }
            $order->setUpdatedAt(time());
            $order->save();
        }
    }
```

**function purpose:**

- I am selling games on ebay.
- If a customers wishes to cancel his order and gets his money back
  (i.e. a Refund) I must open a "Dispute" on ebay first.
- Once a dispute is opened I must wait for the customer to confirm that
  he agrees to the refund (silly as he's the one who told me to refund,
  but that's how it works on ebay).
- This functions gets all disputes opened by me and checks their statuses periodically to see if the customer has replied to the dispute or not.
- The customer may agree (then I refund) or refuse (then I rollback) or may not respond for 7 days (I close the dispute myself then refund).

**Problem**

1. As you can see the code is build on a `if/else` structure which means a new status (a customer closes his account for example) will mean that I need to add a `else if` statement which is a violation for the *Open Closed Principle*.
2. I get a feeling that the function has different layers of abstraction. `getRequestedEbayOrdersFromDB()` is very abstract while the rest of the code has many details.
3. Some of the functions are repeated `insertRecordInOrderHistoryTable()` which just adds a new record to the history Entity table.

**Solution**

I thought about converting the multiple `if/else` to a factory pattern, but I only used factory to create objects not alter behaviors.

Next I thought about using a strategy pattern, but failed to build a good solution.

Any help in appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Maybe use a "factory", but return closures instead of objects? That way you can return the routine that needs to be executed based on the state? Although thinking about it, your factory would still need basically the same `if/else` in order to do this, so it probably won't really gain you anything...

Comment: I can't see where `$orderline` is defined inside your function, is that intentional? :)

Comment: @Jack sorry it's $order :D it's coz I simplified the code I forgot to rename it :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about creating a factory of refund order handlers?

I dont have enough info from the code presented, but Im assuming there is something in the `order` to serve as a key for the type of handler, so you could do the following in `refundAcceptedDisputes`:
(Im a C++ guy, so sorry for the pseudocode)

```
refundOrderHandler = RefundOrderHandlerFactory.getHandler(order);
refundOrderHandler.doRefund(); // Name this method accordingly
```

Then your factory would have a simple if/else to get the type of handler as follows:

```
RefundOrderHandlerFacotry::getHandler(order)) {
  if(isDisputAccepted(order) {
    return handlerA(order);
  }
  else if(isDisputCancelled(order)) {
    return handlerB(order);
  }
  else if(isDisputOlderThan7Days(order)) {
    return handlerC(order);
  }
  // Add new handlers here
}
```

The logic to determine the type of handler would have to be placed in the Factory, or made accessible to it.

You will then have to make a class for each type of `RefundHandler` with `RefundHandlerBase` as the base class that will have an abstract method `doRefund()`
Notice that all of the logic related to refunds is contained in the appropriate class. To add more refund handlers, you will have to create a class to handle it, add an `else if` to the factory, and the appropriate logic to determine the type of `RefundHandler`.

Comment: +1 that's actually what I was trying to achieve with the Factory pattern :) a question though... the return should be `return new handlerA(order);` right? as I need to operate on the entity inside the handler itself.

Comment: Ya, the created object should definitely have the order, I'll update the answer accordingly, thanks.